# Handler.postdelay() not working inside recycler view on scroll state change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-handler, onscrolllistener

I'm basically trying to execute a method in my `RecyclerView` inside on `scroll state change` here I'm using a `Handler` thread to execute a method after some delay but the method is not getting executed at all but however if I put that method outside the handler thread it's getting executed successfully so my question is why am I unable to run `Handler` thread inside `RecyclerView`  `onscroll` here is my code please take a look.

```
rvsongs!!.addOnScrollListener(object: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
                override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                if(newState== SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    val timerHandler = Handler()
                    var updater:Runnable?=null
                    updater = object:Runnable {
                        override fun run() {
                            rvsongs!!.setIndexBarVisibility(false)//this method is not getting executed however when put outside handler thread it's executed without any problem
                        }
                    }
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(updater,100)
                }
                else
                {
                    rvsongs!!.setIndexBarVisibility(true)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Someone help please i'm really stuck

Comment: I just do a test executing a Handler inside onScroll event which shows a Toast. It works for me. Is setIndexBarVisibility a custom function?

Comment: Yes actually i'm using a custom recycler view from this library you should take look
https://github.com/myinnos/AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView

Comment: here rvsongs.setIndexBarVisibility is used to set visiblity of that a-z bar as shown in library screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `setIndexBarVisibilty` after the complete `onScrollStateChanged` is processed. In other words, the `recyclerView` is rendered before `setIndexBatVisibility`.

To solve this, just call `invalidate` after `setIndexBarVisibility`

```
       ...
       var updater:Runnable?=null
        updater = object:Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                rvsongs!!.setIndexBarVisibility(false)
                rvsongs.invalidate()
            }
        }
        ...
```